# All direct and indirect key of a value from map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. My requirement is to get all the direct and indirect key objects for a particular value. 
For example, if data is like:

```
{
 {'Manager'} => ['Jim', 'Michael'],
 {'Jim'} => ['jim.halpert@theoffice.com'],
 {'Fire Marshal'} => ['Manager', 'Dwight'],
 {'Dwight'} => ['dwight.schrute@theoffice.com'],
 {'Michael'} => ['michael.scott@theoffice.com']
}
```

For the input `'michael.scott@theoffice.com'`, I should get below output.

```
['Michael', 'Manager', 'Fire Marshal']
```

I have tried below codes, but it's not working. Please help me.

```
 Map<String, Set<String>> addresses;
 String value;//for which we need to search
 Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
 Set<String> names;
 do {
    names = addresses.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> {
         return entry.getValue().contains(value);
    }).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    results.addAll(names);
 } while (names != null);
```

Comment: you loop does always search for the same `name` - it's obviously not what you want. you have to check if any of the values for a key value is in `names` - and initially you have to add `name` to `names`

Comment: @AKSW, How can I do that, as the names can have more than one value.

Comment: Use a loop indeed?

Answer (score 0):

The program was using the same search value all the time and hence it ran in an endless loop. The below code worked for me even though it wasn't getting the result order as you specified because of the sequence of discovering the keys for the search value I guess:

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> addresses;
    String value = "michael.scott@theoffice.com";
    Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> names = null;
    do {
      String currentSearchValue;
      if(names != null){
        currentSearchValue = names.iterator().next();
      } else {
        currentSearchValue = value;
      }
      names = addresses.entrySet().stream()
                      .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(currentSearchValue))
                      .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet());
      results.addAll(names);
    } while (names != null && !names.isEmpty());
  }
```

Comment: Hey @Fana, I appreciate your effort. This will solve the issue, but only till 2nd level. But how to get all the possible values. `'Fire Marshal'` will be missing with this code.

Comment: When I ran the code, I got the following result: `[Fire Marshal, Manager, Micheal]` so `Fire Marshal` is there, just not in the right position as you specified above.

What do you mean by 'till 2nd level'?

Comment: @DKAnsh I wrote the code to produce the outcome you expected in the question as well, the question makes no mention of beyond 2nd level